# Slow Line2D rendering in matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, rendering

I am trying to use Line2D to render a line between the last point clicked on a polygon and the user's mouse. My current code currently works, but it lags FOREVER between renders, so that the line lags way behind the mouse. Current relevant code is:

```
#in constructor 
cid2 = self.ui.canvas2.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.renderMeasureLine)

#This gets called and is laggy
def renderMeasureLine(self, mouseEvent):            
    if self.measuring and mouseEvent.inaxes == self.ui.canvas2.axes and len(self.pointListX) > 0:

        if self.dotted_line in self.ui.canvas2.axes.lines:
            self.ui.canvas2.axes.lines.remove(self.dotted_line)
        self.dotted_line = Line2D([self.pointListX[-1],mouseEvent.xdata],[self.pointListY[-1],mouseEvent.ydata],
                                   color=color, axes=self.ui.canvas2.axes, ls = '--')
        self.ui.canvas2.axes.add_line(self.dotted_line)
        self.ui.canvas2.draw()
```

================================================================================

```
#mpl canvas class
class MyDynamicMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):
    """A canvas that updates itself every second with a new plot."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        MyMplCanvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.colorMap = cmap.bone

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        self.axes.imshow(self.data, cmap = cmap.bone)

    def update_figure(self, dataOverride = None):
        if self.data is not None or dataOverride is not none:
            FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
            self.axes.clear()
            if dataOverride is not None:
                self.axes.imshow(dataOverride, cmap = self.getColorMap())
            else:
                self.axes.imshow(self.data, cmap = self.getColorMap())
        self.draw()
```

So essentially, every time the mouse moves, I want to update a dotted line between the last polygon point clicked and the current new mouse position. This works, but it is SUPER laggy. Any ideas??

Edit: Picture of what's going on. The dotted line is what is slow.

[image]

Comment: Use blitting, else matplotlib will redraw the whole figure just to update the line. There are examples on the matplotlib site. Else have a good look at the source of cursor class in the matplotlib source dir.

Comment: Ah, this is what I was looking for, but couldn't find. I will give this a shot when I get the chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not create a new `Line2D` for every mouse move. A `Line2D` can have more than 2 points. So instead, use `Line2D.set_data()` to alter the data in a single `Line2D`.

Drawing one `Line2D` with thousands of points will surely be faster than instantiating and drawing thousands of `Line2D`s.

```
def renderMeasureLine(self, mouseEvent):            
    if (self.measuring and mouseEvent.inaxes == self.ui.canvas2.axes
            and len(self.pointListX) > 0):
        if self.dotted_line in self.ui.canvas2.axes.lines:
            x, y = self.dotted_line.get_data()
            x.append(mouseEvent.xdata)
            y.append(mouseEvent.ydata)
            self.dotted_line.set_data(x, y)
        else:
            self.dotted_line = Line2D(
                [self.pointListX[-1],mouseEvent.xdata],
                [self.pointListY[-1],mouseEvent.ydata],
                color=color, axes=self.ui.canvas2.axes, ls = '--')
            self.ui.canvas2.axes.add_line(self.dotted_line)

        self.ui.canvas2.blit(self.ui.canvas2.axes.bbox)
        self.ui.canvas2.draw_idle()
```

Comment: Thanks, this gets me towards the solution, I have spent the last hour trying to figure out a way to make it so that, if the mouse moves and doesn't end on a render count, it will draw a new line...can't figure it out with matplotlib or qt (even by hacking...)

Comment: Actually, this just also makes is choppy and off the mark when you stop moving the mouse :/ Perhaps using Line2D is just not a good solution for this.

Comment: Maybe, instead of counting the number of calls to `renderMeasureLine`, we should be remembering the end point of the last line drawn. Then compute the distance between that end point and the new mouse position. If that distance is greater than `dmin` and less than `dmax`, then draw the line. `dmin` will stop very short lines from being drawn, and `dmax` will stop jerky lines from being drawn.

Comment: Ahhh, I will try this when I get the chance later today and let you know if it works! Good idea :)

Comment: I think tillsten is right -- study how the [`Cursor` class](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/widgets.py#L737) does it. In addition to that, I've added some code above to show how you may draw the entire line with one `Line2D` instead of many `Line2D`s.

Comment: Yeah, per tillsten's suggestion, changed code to use blit and draw_idle. Edited your answer to reflect this (it is pending in edits as I do not have edit privs). Thanks guys! Works perfect.